Automate the Snowflake reports to email
is there a way to automate the snowflake to send an email report (csv) to the recipient?
I currently managed to create the dashboard in the snowflake and I can download it but looking for the automation possibilities to send the query outcome to email address.
Thank you

Basically 3 components are required:

building message body - SQL, Snowpark UDF(Python, Scala, Java)
sending message via email - Using SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL
orchestration/scheduling mechanism - Alerts or Tasks

Related: How to include query results in Snowflake email alert notifications
